# strtok de tabulador con 4 espacios C

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de *parsear* un documento, en el cual cada línea tiene *strings* separados por *tabs* (cada *tab* son 4 espacios en blanco), pero a la hora de realizar un `strtok` no estoy siendo capaz de reconocer esos espacios en blanco.

Este es el fragmento de código en cuestión:

```
if((toks[0] != '\r') && (toks[0] != '\n') && (toks[0] != '\000')){
  while ((toks = strtok(NULL, "    ")) != NULL){
    if ((strcmp(toks, "\r\n") != 0) && (strcmp(toks, "\r") != 0) && (strcmp(toks, "\n") != 0)){
      i++;
      inputs = realloc(inputs,i*sizeof(char*));
      inputs[i-1] = toks;
      numArgs++;
    }
  }
}
```

No soy capaz de hacer el `strtok` del `while` para que me reconozca los 4 espacios, un ejemplo de línea que debería de poder *parsear* es:

```
hola----¿----que----tal----?\000\000
```

Donde cada '`-`' representa un caracter `' '`

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: la separacion por ejemplo entre 'hola' y '¿' son 4 espacios

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: los espacios son de barra espaciadora de verdad o son tabulados?

Comment: No lo se, el fichero me lo pasan ya creado y yo tengo que parsearlo, no se si esta hecho con 4 espacios de barra espaciadora o con un tab de 4 espacios

Comment: si usas strtok(cadena," ") te va a sacar todos los espacios que tenga no hace falta hacerle 4 espacios, agrega un strtok(cadena,"\t") asi contemplas el tabulado y cuentanos

Comment: he modificado el while por esta linea: while (((toks = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) || (toks = strtok(NULL, "\t")) != NULL) pero sigue igual, no entra dentro del bucle.

Comment: claro, la separacion entre cualquier palabra de esta linea: hola    ¿    que    tal    ?\000\000 son 4 espacios

Comment: **No**. Ni parecido. 4 espacios es `----`, o sea, 4 caracteres. **1** tabulador es **un solo caracter `\t`**

Comment: claro y eso es lo que ocurre la linea es `hola----¿----que----tal----?\000\000`

Comment: Pues no mezcles los conceptos, hombre :-) Has dicho `no se si esta hecho con 4 espacios de barra espaciadora o con un tab de 4 espacios`. Vas a confundir a quién quiera responderte :-)

Comment: Sublime Text al hacer un tab te mete 4 caracteres `' '` entonces no se si este fichero ha sido creado con tabs `\t` con con tabs de 4 `' '`, estaba tratando de responder a la pregunta de @FrancoRolando

Comment: pon todos los caracteres que quieras eliminar dentro de un strtok(cadena," \t\n\r\0" o pon un link del archivo y tratamos de solucionarlo

Comment: no se si habra opcion en esta plataforma de subir ficheros, si no os paso un enlace de mega: https://mega.nz/#!kJcwHYxb!SRWjn-sGI8BnLxa7PhUjzIK7KPe87DNQLXyraB1J3no la idea es poder extraer cada elemento del fichero en la variable (toks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te funciona porque [`strtok( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) no se usa así:

> **char* strtok( char* str, const char* delim );**
>   
>   Parameters:
>   **str** -   pointer to the null-terminated byte string to tokenize
>   **delim**   -   pointer to the null-terminated byte string identifying delimiters

En `delim` pasas un puntero **a una lista de caracteres**; puedes pasarle, por ejemplo, `"abc"`, y te *separará* **por cualquiera de ellos**, `a`, `b` o `c`. Pero **no** te buscara `abc`.

Para buscar un conjunto de caracteres **repetido**, una posible opción es usar [`strstr( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr), que te buscará **una cadena dentro de otra**, que es lo que en realidad quieres hacer. Usándola, recorrer una cadena buscando las separaciones es muy simple:

```
char *ptr = "una cadena    de    texto";
while( ptr = (strstr( ptr, "    " ) ) ) {
  ptr += 4; // Nos saltamos los 4 espacios iniciales.

  // Hacemos lo que queramos hacer ...
}
```

Puesto que **no** es equivalente a `strtok( )`, para poder *trocear* una cadena hay que hacer algunos cambios en nuestro método:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) {
  const char buff[] = "  Esto  no  es  mas  que  una  simple  cadena  de  prueba  ";

  const char *start = strstr( buff, "  " );

  if( start == buff ) start += 2; // Tamaño de los espacios.

  while( 1 ) {
    const char *end = strstr( start, "  " );

    if( !end ) break;

    printf( "%.*s\n", (int)( end - start ), start );
    start = end + 2; // Tamaño de los espacios
  }

  if( *start ) printf( "%s\n", start );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Utilizandolo eso, se me queda en un bucle infinito y no pasa de la primera linea del fichero, si que entra dentro del bucle pero esta constantemente haciendo la comparacion del while sobre la primera linea :/

Comment: Teniendo esta linea: `hola----¿----que----tal----?\000\000` tras el primer strstr() se me queda asi: `----¿----que----tal----?` y el resto de iteraciones del while, el strstr siempre saca esto y no avanza, se queda en un bucle infinito

Comment: Perdona @D_94, me ha pillado de regreso del curro. Hay que usar una variable auxiliar que haga de índice. He corregido el ejemplo.

Comment: se me queda igual :/ que en el comentario anterior, en los comentarios de la pregunta he subido el fichero que estoy tratando de parsear, por si sirve de ayuda

Comment: @D_94 jejeje ... perdona otra vez. Estas fechas son malas para responder. Corregido. Hay que avanzar la variable, sino efectivamente se queda en bucle. Esto me pasa por no comprobar el código <:-)

Comment: jajajaja tranquil@ en cuanto pueda, lo pruebo y comento :)

Comment: @D_94 Piensa que `strstr( )` **no** es equivalente a `strtok( )`. No te *corta* la cadena, solo te dice donde empieza la cadena buscada. Tendrás que cambiar tu método.

Comment: Muchas gracias al final si me sirvio! :) tuve que cambiar un poco las cosas, si